# Remove duplicated numbers in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string

40993648 70381211 - PAOLA MILENA PEREZ SUAREZ40993648 70381211 - CARLOS FERNANDO PEREZ CADAVID

The numbers can change.

So I want to eliminate this duplicated numbers

40993648 **70381211** - PAOLA MILENA PEREZ SUAREZ **40993648** 70381211 - CARLOS FERNANDO PEREZ CADAVID

Meaning: the second numeric secuence (70378111) and the third numeric secuence (40993648).

How I do that?

note: all the string can change everytime.

Comment: So you want to *always* delete the second and third numeric sequence? Are they guaranteed to be duplicated like you have mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to capture everything *but* the numbers you don't want, and then join them back together.

http://jsfiddle.net/9FCft/

**JavaScript**

```
var str = "40993648 70381211 - PAOLA MILENA PEREZ SUAREZ 40993648 70381211 - CARLOS FERNANDO"
var regex = /(\d+) \d+(.* )\d+ (\d+.*)/
var result = str.match(regex)

result.slice(1,result.length).join("")
/* 40993648 - PAOLA MILENA PEREZ SUAREZ 70381211 - CARLOS FERNANDO */
```

**EDIT:** Simply replace the spaces with commas in `var regex`.

http://jsfiddle.net/9FCft/1/

**JavaScript**

```
var str = "40993648,70381211 - PAOLA MILENA PEREZ SUAREZ 40993648,70381211 - CARLOS FERNANDO PEREZ CADAVID"
var regex = /(\d+),\d+(.* )\d+,(\d+.*)/
var result = str.match(regex)

result.slice(1,result.length).join("")
/* 40993648 - PAOLA MILENA PEREZ SUAREZ 70381211 - CARLOS FERNANDO PEREZ CADAVID */
```

**Resources:**

http://www.regular-expressions.info is a good place to read up on regular expressions in general. Most languages provide support for regular expressions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions provides great documentation specifically for JavaScript.

[RegexPal](http://regexpal.com) is great for testing out regex in JavaScript as well.

Comment: @thaskell can you help me with this string please? 40993648,70381211 - PAOLA MILENA PEREZ SUAREZ  40993648,70381211 - CARLOS FERNANDO PEREZ CADAVID btw: where you learn this?

Comment: @JuanFernandoz I've updated the answer as well as provided some resources you may find helpful.

Comment: wow thanks. I bother you again for the last time (I make a mistake, sorry) 40993648,70381211 - PAOLA MILENA PEREZ SUAREZ40993648,70381211 - CARLOS FERNANDO PEREZ CADAVID and I said again: thanks very helpfull!

Comment: Ideally it would be best to format the string as nicely as possible before writing a crazy regular expression... But you could do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/9FCft/3/

Answer (score 1):

I used JQuery. The following code just removes the second and the third numeric sequence. I hope to suits you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p></p>
        <script>
        var str = "40993648 70381211 - PAOLA MILENA PEREZ SUAREZ 40993648 70381211 - CARLOS FERNANDO PEREZ CADAVID";
        var arr = str.split(' ');
        var new_arr = [];
        var counter = 0;

        $.map(arr, function(n, i) {
            if ( $.isNumeric(n) ) {
                if ( ( counter !== 1 ) && ( counter !== 2 ) ) {
                    new_arr.push(n);
                }
                counter++;
            } else {
                new_arr.push(n);
            }
            return n;
        });
        $('p').append(new_arr.join(' '));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge! le hecharé un vistazo! :)